# moving marker google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i'm using google map API and i would like to move the makers.
I use the following code:

```
marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(driver.location_latitude, driver.location_longitude ) );
```

the problem is that it duplicate the maker instead of just moving it.

Comment: Just delete the old marker..

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to explain the problem.  The code you posted should move the marker.  There is something you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
marker.setMap(null);

marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(driver.location_latitude, driver.location_longitude ) );

marker.setMap(map);
```

note that `map` is your map object.

Comment: Not sure why you think that should matter.  If marker is a google.maps.Marker object, setPosition should just work.

Comment: @geocodezip i tested `setPosition()` method and it's work correctly but sometimes marker hide in map, when i use `setMap(null) & setMap(map)` methods before & after `setPostion()` method it's allways works

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes marker hide in map"?  Doesn't sound like the problem the original question is asking (what does that have to do with the original question of "moving marker").